# spacy: add lemmatizer lookup for Dutch (nl) language

Tags: python, spacy, lemmatization

*I'am using Spacy 2.0.11 with Dutch language model nl_core_news_sm (nl).  How can I add the lemmatization lookup similar to the implementation for German (de)?*

I tried the following steps:

- add lookup to **init**.py in the language folder (nl)
- add lemmatizer.py in the language folder (nl)

This resulted in the following error after 'nlp = nl_core_news_sm.load()' or 'from spacy.lang.nl import Dutch':

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.lang.nl.lemmatizer'
ImportError: [E048] Can't import language nl from spacy.lang

Comment: Just for the record, because this is an old question, [spacy has a Dutch lemmatizer now](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-lookups-data/tree/master/spacy_lookups_data/data) - and even has lemma rules which the German lemmatizer doesn't have (yet).

Comment: Nice, I will have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, your approach is correct – if you copy exactly how it's implemented in German and other languages that implement the lookup, it should work.

I suspect your problem here is actually a different one: According to the error message, it can't actually find the `spacy.lang.nl.lemmatizer` module, so spaCy now fails to import the `Dutch` language class. Are you sure the `lemmatizer.py` file exists in the correct place, and is imported correctly? (If you're not doing it already, I'd also recommend running your development installation in a separate environment and build spaCy from source, to make sure there are no weird conflicts).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that is not possible, the english model includes a lemmatizer (see [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/en/__init__.py#L10)) and the Dutch one does not ([here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/nl/__init__.py)).

it is a component hand-written based on the morphology of the language, so while Spacy has models for Dutch this specific function is not there .